# CSS Positioning Troubleshooting with Float

Tags: html, css, css-position, positioning

I can't quite get my scenario to play out in JSFiddle, so I'm posting the link to the webpage I'm currently working on here: http://www.lymemd.org/indexmm4.php

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dHahe/)

Some relevant CSS is as follows:

```
#leftcolumn {
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
}
#rightcolumn {
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
}
#twitter {
   min-height: 250px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-right: 15px;
}
#whatsnew {
   min-height: 500px;
   background: #f0f7cb;
   outline:#FFFFFF solid thick;
   margin-top: 15px;
   margin-right: 15px
}
#supportus {
   min-height: 445px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   background: #f0f7cb;
   outline:#FFFFFF solid thick;
}
#dianerehm {
   min-height: 200px;
   background: #f0f7cb;
   outline:#FFFFFF solid thick;
}
```

And below is the HTML section I'm having trouble with:

```
<div id="rightcolumn">         
    <div id="supportus">
    <h6>Support Us</h6>

            <img src="images/race2.jpg" width="180" height="360"/>


    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" style="display: inline-block;">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="DM87UZYCZW5CU">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>

    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" style="display: inline-block;">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="DM87UZYCZW5CU">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

I'd like to have text centered to the right of the "race2.jpg" image that goes down along the column where there is currently empty space.  Does anyhow know how to do this?  I'm not sure if I need more float commands or in-line commands, but I think it should be possible.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would try simply wrapping your image with a `DIV` and including another `DIV` for the text:

```
<div id="rightcolumn">         
    <div id="supportus">
        <h6>Support Us</h6>
        <div style="float:left">
            <img src="images/race2.jpg" width="180" height="360"/>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left; text-align:center">
            CENTERED TEXT HERE!
        </div>
        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" style="display: inline-block; clear:left;">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="DM87UZYCZW5CU">
            <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
            <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
        </form>

        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" style="display: inline-block;">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="DM87UZYCZW5CU">
            <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
            <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure of the layout you are looking for, but something like this may be a start: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dHahe/2/)

```
#leftcolumn {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
#bigimage {
    position: absolute;
}
#rightcolumn {
    width: 500px;

}

#whatsnew {
    min-height: 300px;
    background: #f0f7cb;
    outline:#FFFFFF solid thick;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px
}

#supportus {
    padding-top: 30px;
    width: 700px;
    min-height: 370px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: #f0f7cb;
    text-align: center;
}
#dianerehm {
    min-height: 200px;
    background: #f0f7cb;
    outline:#FFFFFF solid thick;
}
form {
    width: 130px;
    margin: auto;
}
```